# referencing a dynamically created element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated

I have an input field(`search_text`), which shows the images (`id="demo2"`) from a database when the user puts in more than 1 letter.

And then I have a draw function (`draw()`) that is supposed to do something when the image is being clicked, (after it got displayed from the database).

The problem is the image (`id="demo2"`) does not exist in the Html DOM, only after the user has put in more than 1 letter.

Now, I have:

```
function myFunction(){
  console.log('success');
  alert("I am an alert box!");
  console.log('success2');
 var x = document.getElementById("demo2");
 console.log(x);
 x.addEventListener("click", myFunct);
 console.log(x);
}

function myFunct(){
  currentImg=document.getElementById("demo2");
 draw();
}


function myFunction2(){
  //alert("I am an alert box!");
  var x = document.getElementById("search_text").value;
  if (x.length >2){myFunction();} 
  }
```

which works when I slowley type in the searchterm and the alertbox comes and after that, when I click the image, the `draw()` function works.

When I take out the `alert` it won't work. Somehow the alert lets the user wait until the image is loaded/created. How do I achieve this without the alert?

Thanks!

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery function `$.on()` to bind an action to a not yet created element. You just specify it to be on an alement that exists when the code is running, such as the `body` element.

See the fiddle below. The `HEY` button wont appear until after 3 seconds, but since we bind the click event to it as described above, we wont have any problem.

```js
//This is how you bind to a dynamically created element
$('body').on('click', '.myclass', myFunction);

setTimeout(function() {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className = "myclass";
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("HEY"));

  $('#button-cell').append(button);
}, 3000);

function myFunction() {
  alert("It's working!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="button-cell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Even though this works, I'd suggest you might look into adding your elements directly and then toggling their visibility.

Comment: Thanks ! works ! Thank you so much!  I decided to call the `myFunct()` function though, otherwise you have to click twice. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout` to make it run in a separate thread which would be what `alert` does otherwise:

```
function myFunction2(){
  setTimeout(function(){
       var x = document.getElementById("search_text").value;
       if (x.length >2){
           myFunction();
       } 
  },100)//keep minimal time.
}
```

**Suggestion:**

> **Why don't you add element to DOM toggle the display of an element instead of creating it after typing 2 chars?**